# How to call php class methods in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to retrive some code from a php method using ajax, when a person click a div.

HTML

```
<div class="contenitore">
    <div>
        <input class="idCommento" value="//some number">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="vediRisp">Create text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contenitore">
    <div>
        <input class="idCommento" value="//some number">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="vediRisp">Create text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP (lib/Users.class.php)

```
Class Users{
    public function dammi_i_commenti(arguments){
        return '<div>code</div>';
    }
}
```

(lib/ottieniCose.php)

```
require('Users.class.php');
$login = New Users;

$GLOBAL['current'] == $_GET['adesso'];
print $login->dammi_i_commenti();
```

AJAX

```
$(".vediRisp").on('click', function() {
    var mh = $(this).parentsUntil(".contenitore").find(".idCommento");
    var eeeh = mh.val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "lib/ottieniCose.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            adesso: eeeh,
        },
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

When i click the `.vediRisp` in the console i can read `success`, then `complete`, so I'm thinking that the click and ajax function work, but the page doesn't seem to update its content therefore i think that i'm not calling the method correctly. Anyway if i try to write `var_dump("stuff")` or `print_r("stuff")` in the ottieniCose.php file i get absolultely no result at all, and my guess is that i'm not using the ajax function correctly, or the ottieniCose.php file isn't called.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the response to the page using jquery.

```
.done(function(response) {
        console.log("success");
        $("#<some div id>").html(response)
    })
```

Simply printing it on the php script wont add it to he page.